# Flutter : Unable to redirect to specific screen on Notification click when app is in background but not terminated in iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have used [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) plugin for notifications, on both platforms notifications works fine,

However, I want to redirect user to specific screen on Notification click event. For **Android** side, it's working fine. But for **IOS**, it does not work if app is in background and is not terminated (Works fine if app is terminated).

Here's my code sample for notification integration:

```dart
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onMessage: $message");
    gotoTempPage();
  },
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onLaunch: $message");
    gotoTempPage();
  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onResume: $message");
    gotoTempPage();
  },
);
```

I am using plugin version `firebase_messaging: ^6.0.9`, and flutter version `v1.12.13+hotfix.5`

Already referred these issues [935](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/935), [1757](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1757), [1677](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1677) but nothing helped me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi i had exactly the same issue. So, according to the current documentation of the plugin (firebase_messaging), you should make some modification to your Appdelegate.m/Appdelegate.swift file. 
**This modification is the problem.** 
Remove the following code from your `AppDelegate.swift` or similar in `AppDelegate.m`

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
}
```

It seems to be a bug or issue with this version of firebase_messaging (6.0.9) as in [here](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2009#issue-566165748)

Comment: @Rufw91 I'm about to implement it and searching I found that it has some compatibility issue with `flutter_local_notification`. Are you experiencing some problems on iOS with it? Usual problems are related to background vs foreground receiving messages and local notifications.
Can you confirm that you are able to receive both notifications when in ether mode?
Many thanks

Comment: Hi @Vincenzo i have used without the AppDelegate modification in an iOS app with no problems whatsoever i receive notifications when app is in Foreground, Paused and Terminated. However, im not using `flutter_local_notification`. I don't think (subjective) it should be an issue.